# Installing apache: no VCRUNTIME140.dll despite installing VC_redist.x86.exe

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed VC_redist.x86.exe as instructed by the Apache docs, but when I run `httpd.exe -k install` it gives me the error:

```
this program can't start because vcruntime140.dll is missing
from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Installing VC_redist.x64.exe also did *not* fix the issue.

Why would it be missing? Do I need to restart after installing "VC_redist.x86.exe"? Is there something else?

Comment: Which version of the runtime are you installing? There are *lots* of VC++ runtimes around...

Comment: I installed the latest one from 2015 as the docs suggested: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984

Comment: @Massimo I installed the 2012, 2013 and 2015 ones and it still gives the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the 64-bit version of "VC_redist" worked despite the Apache 2.4 being 32-bit.

Install VC_redist.x64.exe